# What should I say after asking about the price of an article but I don't want to buy?

Tags: spoken-english

In many cases, I ask a seller about the price of an article, but finally I don't want to buy. I don't know how to reply him or her politely in English? What English-speaker usually say thin these cases?

Comment: Before: _wanting to know your price for this, thanks;_ After: _thank you, just wanted to know_. I think that'll do :)

Comment: [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/986/how-would-a-native-say-just-looking-around/988#988).

Comment: Unless you are trying to be really polite, I would just say "Thanks anyway".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link in J.R.'s comment above, the most common response is, "just looking."

> No thanks, I'm just looking.

This is probably one of the more useful phrases to learn in any language.

Also mentioned is the related term "window shopping" but this is a general activity and not something you would usually say to a salesperson.  "Window shopping" implies that you are just *looking* at the items for sale, and you don't intend to *buy* anything.

> My friends and I are going to go down to the mall to do some window shopping.

Of course, there's no reason you can't be blunt, especially if the salesperson is pushy:

> Wow!  That's expensive.
>
> Really?  That much?
>
> I'm sorry, I don't think so.

or my personal favorite

> Hm.  Let me check the price on Amazon ...